# Create IPSEC VPN between three Routers?

Tags: vpn, security, ipsec, networking

I'm attempt to build essentially an IPSEC tunnel mesh between three Cisco IOSv routers.  I've been able to build an IPSEC tunnel between two directly connected routers but once I add the third router it gets complicated.  I'm not sure if I need to create separate Crypto Maps for each connection or if I can use a single Crypto Map for all of them.

Please see the below diagram:
[image]

I'm trying to keep it simple by only using static routes between the routers.  I think the problem lies with Router2.  As it stands right now PC3 can successfully ping PC1, but cannot ping PC2.  Likewise, PC1 can ping PC3, but cannot ping PC2.  Router1 can ping Router3, but cannot ping Router2.  And likewise, Router 3 can ping Router1, but cannot ping Router2.

Any help would be great!

Here are the configs:

**Router1 -**

```
Current configuration : 3807 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 15:37:40 UTC Tue Apr 7 2020
!
version 15.6
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
ethernet lmi ce
!
!
!
mmi polling-interval 60
!
!
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
!
!
!
!
!
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
crypto isakmp key cisco address 10.10.10.3
crypto isakmp key cisco address 10.10.10.2
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set TSET esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
 mode tunnel
!
!
crypto map TST 10 ipsec-isakmp
 set peer 10.10.10.3
 set peer 10.10.10.2
 set transform-set TSET
 match address 100
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.31.225 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 crypto map TST
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 172.16.32.224 255.255.255.252 10.10.10.2
ip route 172.16.33.224 255.255.255.252 10.10.10.3
!
!
!
access-list 100 permit ip host 10.10.10.1 host 10.10.10.3
access-list 100 permit ip host 10.10.10.1 host 10.10.10.2
access-list 100 permit ip any any
!
control-plane
!
banner exec ^C
**************************************************************************
* IOSv is strictly limited to use for evaluation, demonstration and IOS  *
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
banner incoming ^C
**************************************************************************
* IOSv is strictly limited to use for evaluation, demonstration and IOS  *
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
banner login ^C
**************************************************************************
* IOSv is strictly limited to use for evaluation, demonstration and IOS  *
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
no scheduler allocate
!
end
```

**Router2 -**

```
Current configuration : 3944 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 15:42:55 UTC Tue Apr 7 2020
!
version 15.6
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router2
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
ethernet lmi ce
!
!
!
no process cpu autoprofile hog
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
!
!
!
!
!
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
no cdp run
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
crypto isakmp key cisco address 10.10.10.3
crypto isakmp key cisco address 10.10.10.1
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set TSET esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
 mode tunnel
!
!
!
crypto map TST 10 ipsec-isakmp
 set peer 10.10.10.3
 set peer 10.10.10.1
 set transform-set TSET
 match address 100
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.32.225 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no cdp enable
 crypto map TST
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no cdp enable
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 172.16.31.224 255.255.255.252 10.10.10.1
ip route 172.16.33.224 255.255.255.252 10.10.10.3
!
!
!
access-list 100 permit ip host 10.10.10.2 host 10.10.10.1
access-list 100 permit ip host 10.10.10.2 host 10.10.10.3
access-list 100 permit ip any any
!
control-plane
!
banner exec ^C
**************************************************************************
* IOSv is strictly limited to use for evaluation, demonstration and IOS  *
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
banner incoming ^C
**************************************************************************
* IOSv is strictly limited to use for evaluation, demonstration and IOS  *
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
banner login ^C
**************************************************************************
* IOSv is strictly limited to use for evaluation, demonstration and IOS  *
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
no scheduler allocate
!
end
```

**Router3 -**

```
Current configuration : 3909 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 15:47:48 UTC Tue Apr 7 2020
!
version 15.6
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router3
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
ethernet lmi ce
!
!
!
no process cpu autoprofile hog
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
!
!
!
!
!
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
no cdp run
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
crypto isakmp key cisco address 10.10.10.1
crypto isakmp key cisco address 10.10.10.2
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set TSET esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
 mode tunnel
!
!
!
crypto map TST 10 ipsec-isakmp
 set peer 10.10.10.1
 set peer 10.10.10.2
 set transform-set TSET
 match address 100
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.33.225 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.10.10.3 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no cdp enable
 crypto map TST
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no cdp enable
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 172.16.31.224 255.255.255.252 10.10.10.1
ip route 172.16.32.224 255.255.255.252 10.10.10.2
!
!
!
access-list 100 permit ip host 10.10.10.3 host 10.10.10.1
access-list 100 permit ip host 10.10.10.3 host 10.10.10.2
access-list 100 permit ip any any
!
control-plane
!
banner exec ^C
**************************************************************************
* IOSv is strictly limited to use for evaluation, demonstration and IOS  *
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
banner incoming ^C
**************************************************************************
* IOSv is strictly limited to use for evaluation, demonstration and IOS  *
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
banner login ^C
**************************************************************************
* IOSv is strictly limited to use for evaluation, demonstration and IOS  *
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
no scheduler allocate
!
end
```

When Router2 attempts to ping Router1 I get the following error message:

```
Router2#ping 10.10.10.1
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.10.10.1, timeout is 2 seconds:

*Apr  7 16:25:52.823: %CRYPTO-4-RECVD_PKT_INV_SPI: decaps: rec'd IPSEC packet has invalid spi for destaddr=10.10.10.1, prot=50, spi=0xC94E3260(3377345120), srcaddr=10.10.10.3, input interface=GigabitEthernet0/1
*Apr  7 16:25:52.824: %CRYPTO-4-RECVD_PKT_NOT_IPSEC: Rec'd packet not an IPSEC packet. (ip) vrf/dest_addr= /10.10.10.1, src_addr= 10.10.10.3, prot= 50.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate crypto-map section and separate access list for each tunnel.  Something roughly like this:

```
crypto map TST 10 ipsec-isakmp
set peer <router2>
set transform-set TST
match address <router1-router2>
!
crypto map TST 20 ipsec-isakmp
set peer <router3>
set transform-set TST
match address <router1-router3>
```

Note that you can't route between sites.  In other words if the tunnel from R1 to R3 goes down, you can't get from R1 to R3 through R2.  That requires a different configuration with GRE or VTI tunnels